# список произведений элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу помощи у сообщества, задача простейшая, но решить никак не получается.
Дано Список чисел, пусть будет `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
необходимо получить список, в котором каждый элемент равен произведению всех остальных элементов списка: `[24, 12, 8, 6]` - в случае с примером.
у меня получилось решить задачу для суммы:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
print([sum(a) - i for i in a])
```

как мне сделать для того, что бы получить произведения?

```
def product(a):
    pr = 1
    for i in a:
        pr *= i
    return pr
ans = [int(product(a)/i) for i in a]
print(ans)
```

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает ваш код? Я вижу только один недстаток, возможно, не существенный. Ладно, два. То есть три. Но с ними можно жить.

Comment: перечислите, пожалуйста, недостатки. Не устраивает, громоздкостью, чувствую, есть другие, более простые и изящные решения.

Comment: ну например, произведение всех чисел списка считает столько раз, сколько чисел в списке. А ведь оно не изменится, поэтому достаточно посчитать его только один раз и потом делить на каждый элемент. Приводить к int тоже нет смысла, там уже и без этого число.

Comment: Три недостатка: много раз вычисляется `product` (линейная сложность -> квадратичная сложность; `int(... / ...)` теряет точность, лучше `... // ...`;  неправильно обрабатываются нули в списке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде я вижу три недостатка:

- много раз вычисляется `product`, что делает ваше решение квадратичным по сложности, а можно уложиться в линейное время;
- `int(... / ...)` теряет точность, переводя целые (которые в Питоне не ограничены) в вещественные (у которых 53 бита точности). Вот пример:

> ```
> [9007199254740993, 9007199254740991] -> [9007199254740991, 9007199254740992]
> ```

- неправильно обрабатываются нули в списке.

Возможное решение всех этих проблем ниже.

Код из вопроса `int(... / ...)` позволяет предположить что в списке только целые.

Наивное решение которое использует свежий Питон (3.8 и выше):

```
def naive_partial_products(a):
    # если Питон не свежий, то вычислите произведение так
    # p = functools.reduce(operator.mul, a, 1)
    p = math.prod(a)
    return [p // v for v in a]
```

Это короткое быстрое решение, которое хорошо работает пока в массиве нет нулей. Если нули есть, надо разбирать случаи. Если ноль один, то в ответе все нули кроме одного элемента. Если нулей больше одного, то в ответе одни нули.

Кроме нулей надо внимательно проследить как обрабатываются короткие массивы.

После учёта всех возможностей получается такой симпатичный монстрик:

```
import math


def partial_products(a):
    zc = a.count(0)
    if zc > 1:
        return [0] * len(a)
    p = math.prod(v for v in a if v != 0)
    if zc == 0:
        return [p // v for v in a]
    return [p if v == 0 else 0 for v in a]


def check(a):
    print(f'{a} -> {partial_products(a)}')


check([])
check([0])
check([0, 0])
check([0, 0, 0])
check([10])
check([0, 10])
check([1, 2, 3, 4])
check([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
check([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

> ```
> $ python partial-products.py 
> [] -> []
> [0] -> [1]
> [0, 0] -> [0, 0]
> [0, 0, 0] -> [0, 0, 0]
> [10] -> [1]
> [0, 10] -> [10, 0]
> [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [24, 12, 8, 6]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] -> [24, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4] -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> ```

**P.S.** Предыдущее решение длинное и сложное со множеством краевых случаев. Можно сделать немного изящнее, но потребуется дополнительная линейная память.

Из списка `[1, 2, 3, 4]` построим два списка с накопительными произведениями:

> ```
> a  = [ 1,  2,  3,  4]
> lr = [ 1,  1,  2,  6]   # lr[i] = prod(a[     :i])
> rl = [24, 12,  4,  1]   # rl[i] = prod(a[i + 1: ])
> ```

Список `lr` строится за линейное время проходом по `a` слева направо.
Список `rl` строится за линейное время проходом по `a` справа налево. Его потом придётся перевернуть. Поэлементное произведение `lr` и `rl` - ответ.

Код:

```
def cum_prod(seq):
    p = 1
    for v in seq:
        yield p
        p *= v


def partial_products(a):
    lr = cum_prod(a)
    rl = reversed(tuple(cum_prod(reversed(a))))
    return [a * b for a, b in zip(lr, rl)]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

print([math.prod(a[:i] + a[i + 1:]) for i in range(len(a))])
```

так есть гуд?

```
import math
a = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

temp_p = math.prod(a)
temp_i = a.count(0)
if temp_p == 0 and temp_i == 1:
    i = a.index(0)
    print([0] * i + [math.prod(a[:i] + a[i + 1:])] + [0] * (len(a) - i - 1))
elif temp_i > 1:
    print([0] * len(a))
else:
    print([temp_p // i for i in a])
```

Comment: Квадратичное время расчёта не есть гут, когда линейное сделать нетрудно

Comment: Стало хуже. Лучше сделайте накопительные произведения слева и справа. Будет и коротко и быстро.

Comment: Можно пример для облегчения понимания алгоритма?

Comment: За линейное время можно сосчитать `[prod(a[:1]), prod(a[:2]), prod(a[:3]), ...]` - накопительные произведения слева. Аналогично считаются накопительные произведения справа. Из двух списков накопительных произведений за линейное время строится список неполных произведений.

Comment: `так есть гуд?` -  нет. Вы понимаете, что считаете одни и те же произведения много раз? Посчитайте `lprod[i]=lprod[i-1]*a[i]` слева направо и `rprod[i]=rprod[i+1]*a[i]` справа налево

Comment: Если вы о первом решении, то понял что имеется ввиду.